# 0 (Zero) added for for empty 'float' fields instead of null after updating MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have kept default values as null and have allowed null values for my data fields and it was working fine on the last version of MySQL but on the latest version of MySQL, it is updating all float values as 0 and not NULL.

Heres a sample of the form

```
<tr>
                <td>Birth Weight</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="birthweight"  placeholder=" Enter Birth Weight"> Kg</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="DateOfBirth"  name="DateOfBirth" class="Select"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Sex</td>
                <td><select name="sex"  class="Select">
                        <option value ="--"> Select </option>
                          <option value="Male ">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

php :

```
$db = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['DateOfBirth']);
$sx = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['sex']);
$birthwt = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['birthweight']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tab1 (db, sx, birthwt)
VALUES ('$db', '$sx', '$birthwt')";
```

[image]

The other values get updated as null but not float values. I tried searching the other questions ut did not find anything catering to my problem.

Comment: What is the relation to PHP? If it's involved, it may be your PHP code, otherwise, you could remove it from the question as it's irrelevant.

Comment: Don't know if it's causing the problem, but you should be using prepared statements and bind variables, you are open to SQL injection etc.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I am using a php form to input data into the database.

Comment: @NigelRen, is mysqli_real_escape_string, not sufficient to prevent those?

Comment: Yes, so add the OS, browser, webserver, CPU arch and the day of the week, too! No, you are supposed to filter relevant parts from irrelevant parts first, e.g. by creating a [mcve]. Also, you can (and should know how to!) run PHP from the commandline, removing the necessity and uncertainty of the manual input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply added another query below my query which sets the 0 values to null.